# pom.xml error in eclipse(indigo) when creating jboss-as-helloworld project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, jboss

I have a problem when i create jboss-as-helloworld project and it first gives quick fix dialog box.

```
project build error non-resolvable import POM: failure to transfer org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.0.beta1 from http:\\repo1.maven2 was cashed in the local repository,resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central

Project build error:'dependencies.dependency.version'for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing.

Project build error:'dependencies.dependency.version'for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotation-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing.

Project build error:'dependencies.dependency.version'for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing.
```

**It gives this errors when it start to run..**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http:\\www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Downloading: http:\\repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-6.0/3.0.0.Beta1/jboss-javaee-6.0-3.0.0.Beta1.pom

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]   

[ERROR]   The project org.jboss.as.quickstarts:jboss-as-helloworld:7.1.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Heshan\workspace\helloworld\jboss-as-helloworld\pom.xml) has 4 errors

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.0.Beta1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times out @ line 39, column 22 -> [Help 2]

[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 53, column 19

[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 61, column 19

[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 69, column 19

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http:\\cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

[ERROR] [Help 2] http:\\cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http:\\www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Downloading: http:\\repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-6.0/3.0.0.Beta1/jboss-javaee-6.0-3.0.0.Beta1.pom.

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.jboss.as.quickstarts:jboss-as-helloworld:7.1.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Heshan\workspace\helloworld\jboss-as-helloworld\pom.xml) has 4 errors

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.0.Beta1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times out @ line 39, column 22 -> [Help 2]

[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 53, column 19

[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 61, column 19

[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 69, column 19

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http:\\cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

[ERROR] [Help 2] http:\\cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: did you go thru the help links?

Comment: i wnt thru dat link.. but first i want to solve that quick fix errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:3.0.0.Beta1 from/to central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times out @ line 39, column
>   22 -> [Help 2

Your connection to maven central repo times out. You have a network connectivity issue. Maybe you don't have network connection, or maybe you need to configure a proxy if you do.

By using [this link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-6.0/3.0.0.Beta1/jboss-javaee-6.0-3.0.0.Beta1.pom) you can see the file actually is in there, so you should be able to download it.

Comment: i can go to that link but cannot download. where to copy that file?

Comment: @heshan you're not supposed to copy that file yourself. I was only illustrating that it exists so maven should work unless you have network issues.